# Ошибка RECORD_FAIL_TIMEOUT при копировании 200ГБ на винчестер

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть винчестеры на 2 и 4 терабайта, оба монтированы с файловой системой ext4, при запуске Ubuntu 14.0.4 все нормально. Когда копирую с Win7 по локальной сети 200ГБ, спустя какое-то время появляется ошибка `RECORD_FAIL_TIMEOUT`. Как понял из ошибки, превышен интервал ожидания. С чем это связано? И бывает, что при старте системы выскакивают ошибки при монтировании жестких. Как перенести всю информацию на жесткие диски? И правильно ли я монтирую разделы в `/mnt/sdb1` и с файловой системой ext4?

Comment: Кто вам сообщает о такой ошибке *RECORD_FAIL_TIMEOUT*?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430442/178576).