# Ошибка при копировании больших объемов данных (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, кодировка, сеть

Возникла такая проблема, копирую файлы с винды по локальной сети, около 1 млн файлов весом в 200Гб (простым способом, наутилусом).
После того как скопировалось 411242 файлов 26,6Гб (это последняя попытка) система зависает, и выдает какие-то кракозябры на черном экране, среди которых можно найти sdb1 - это сам винт (4Тб HDD). Смонтирован он в /mnt/sdb1/, фс ext4. Почем так происходит? Ведь если копировать понемногу то все работает нормально.

ЛОГИ dsmeg и syslog: http://rghost.ru/6Mqrjp4PN

Comment: Вопрос подозрительно похож на этот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430364/

Comment: Добавьте, если не сложно, вывод хвоста dmesg'а. Прозреваю, что идут ошибки диска.
Что-нибудь вроде

`dmesg -T|tail -n 25`

сделайте и покажите нам.

Comment: @Regent, похож-похож. только какой из них считать дублем?

Comment: К тому вопросу не имею отношения. Нарыл информацию о том что могли закончиться inode. Если это так то как отследить это и как избежать? Сейчас попробую вариант что предложили выше.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin этот вопрос появился позже, поэтому считать дублем, по-моему, нужно его. Но это если у того вопроса появится правильный ответ.

Comment: Результат dmesg прикрутил в шапку

Comment: Вроде как здесь описано что делать нужно, но я все же не пойму что именно и как правильно! Растолкуйте если это есть решение: http://serverfault.com/questions/396768/ext4-file-system-max-inode-limit-can-anyone-please-explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

возможно, в файловой системе закончились *inode*. посмотреть ситуацию по ним можно для всех примонтированных файловых систем командой `df -i`. пример вывода (в пятом столбце — процент использованных *inode*):

```
$ df -i
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0      920272 207134 713138   23% /
udev           497545    440 497105    1% /dev
tmpfs          499982    769 499213    1% /run
tmpfs          499982      3 499979    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          499982      7 499975    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          499982     14 499968    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      124496    335 124161    1% /boot
tmpfs          499982      9 499973    1% /run/user/1000
```

для конкретной файловой системы можно указать точку монтирования (у автора — /mnt/sdb1):

```
$ df -i /mnt/sdb1
```

или, даже если файловая система не примонтирована, с помощью команды `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep -i inode`. пример вывода:

```
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Inode count:              920272
Free inodes:              713166
Inodes per group:         8144
Inode blocks per group:   509
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1863
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

обратить следует внимание на *inode count* и *free inodes*.

к сожалению, после создания файловой системы *ext** уже невозможно изменить количество *inode* в ней. надо пересоздавать файловую систему (предварительно сохранив куда-нибудь всё её содержимое), указав, например, другой тип использования файловой системы.

задать тип можно параметром `-T usage-type` программы `mkfs.ext4`.

список типов можно посмотреть в `/etc/mke2fs.conf`.

очень большое количество *inode* будет создано, например, для типа *news* (чем меньше *inode_ratio*, тем больше *inode* будет создано, а файловая система будет разбита на большее количество «кусочков» меньшего размера).

а можно, не указывая тип использования, передать программе `mkfs.ext4` непосредственно желаемый *inode_ratio* с помощью параметра `-i`.

например, так:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -i 4096 /dev/sdb1
```

**предупреждение**: только не увлекайтесь уменьшением *inode_ratio*: каждый *inode* «отбирает» несколько байт (задаётся с помощью *inode_size*, который лучше самому не изменять) «полезной ёмкости» для «служебной» информации.

Comment: А как понять какое кол-во инод мне нужно? или сколько их пригодится в будущем?

Comment: заглядывать в будущее нам не дано. значение же *inode_ratio* определяет, насколько мелко будет «порезано» дисковое пространство: это минимальное занимаемое файлом пространство. если даже файл имеет нулевую длину, как минимум один *inode* он всё равно «отгрызает» от файловой системы.

Comment: Я проверил, в данный момент сейчас показывает такое значение: /dev/sdb1 244195328 92489 244102839 1% /mnt/sdb1 - Это говорит о том что не в инодах дело?

Comment: да, дело не в них.

Comment: вы привели лишь концовку вывода `dmesg`. если вы после описываемого сбоя ещё не перезагружали машину, сохраните весь вывод `dmesg` в файл (`dmesg > /tmp/some_file`) и выложите его куда-нибудь. возможно, там найдётся какая-то подсказка.

Comment: Еще /var/log/syslog можно посмотреть.

Comment: Прикрутил dsmeg и syslog в шапку (сервер упал в районе 12ти часов)

Comment: судя по логу, компьютер, видимо, «завис» в 12:15 и был перезагружен в 19:03. поэтому вывод программы *dmesg* в данном случае бесполезен (буфер сообщений ядра «живёт» в оперативной памяти). и именно в  этом направлении (отчего «завис») и надо разбираться. а ошибка при копировании — это уже, судя по всему, следствие.

Comment: @avp, гляньте, пожалуйста, опытным взглядом на выложенный *syslog*. я в нём кроме подвисших *pulseadio* и *avahi*, никаких неполадок не обнаружил.

Comment: А как ее тогда отловить?

Comment: если зависание повторится, то, в первую очередь, надо постараться зафиксировать «кракозябры на черном экране».

Comment: @sanu0074, у меня не качает Logs.zip, говорит "вирус или шпион". Положите оба файла просто в текстовом виде куда-нибудь вроде pastebin.com

Comment: @avp: http://paste2.org/B011XWce . это syslog. dmesg после перезагрузки вряд ли представляет интерес, но на всякий случай: http://paste2.org/enPxN094

Comment: Повторил я процедуру. В этот раз ждал с включенным монитором, система повисла, не работала ни мышка, ни клавиатура, изображение на мониторе зафризилось. Ничего не могу сделать. Скопировалось 10гб на этот раз. Я так подозреваю что ошибка появилась во копирования время больших файлов, ну по 5-10 и более мб.  Еще, не пойму почему, все разы не срабатывает kernel.panic, у меня стоит параметр 10сек. Что дальше делать, не имею понятия((

Comment: @sanu0074,   я посмотрел логи. / Вроде ничего указывающего на ошибку не заметил (не может же в самом деле, ругающийся каждые 3 секунды pulseaudio иметь к этому отношение, да и не установленный nss-myhostname IMHO тоже). Правда, подозреваю, что в этом syslog не отображается  момент зависания. / Можете прислать часть syslog в котором точно есть сообщения во время зависания? (время там отображается)

Comment: @sanu0074, пардон, ошибся. Есть момент зависания. Вот `Jun 17 12:15:41 server pulseaudio[3630]:` последнее сообщение. Следующее уже `Jun 17 19:03:31 server rsyslogd:` после перезагрузки. А перед ними (кроме pulseaudio) `Jun 17 11:44:30 server dbus[659]`,  `Jun 17 12:06:32 server dhclient` и `Jun 17 12:09:01 server CRON` Только мыслей о причинах аварии от этого не добавилось...

Comment: @sanu0074, во-первых, можно точно определиться, связано ли зависание с сетью. для этого следует копировать файлы/каталоги локально, без привлечения сети. во-вторых, ожидание зависания лучше проводить, переключившись на первый виртуальный терминал (`ctrl+alt+f1`, к «графике» можно вернуться где-нибудь на 6-8 терминале — `ctrl+alt+f6` и т.д.) — туда linux может успеть написать «прощальное письмо».

Comment: спасибо, сейчас я проверю диск на повреждения, потом попробую еще раз все сделать

Comment: При форматировании данного диска получил ошибку: Error erasing device: Error writing 1048576 bytes to /dev/sdb1: Input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0). Что это значит?

Comment: это значит, что возникла ошибка при записи на диск. по моему мнению, в подавляющем большинстве случаев это означает наличие аппаратной проблемы (диск, провода, блок питания, контроллер на материнской плате и т.д. и т.п.).

Comment: как его можно вылечить? если это можно..