# Ограничение инодов на VPS

Tags: vps

На VPS сработало ограничение по количеству инодов. 
Что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

узнать количество *inode*, которое занимают файлы/подкаталоги указанного каталога, можно с помощью программы `du` с опцией `--inodes`.

пример.

подсчёт для всех каталогов внутри каталога `/var` (с сортировкой и обрезкой до пяти последних строк):

```
$ du --inodes -s /var/* | sort -n | tail -n 5
53  /var/backups
54  /var/tmp
202 /var/cache
291 /var/log
11892   /var/lib
```

и глубже — в каталоге `/var/lib`:

```
$ du --inodes -s /var/lib/* | sort -n | tail -n 5
97  /var/lib/systemd
98  /var/lib/gconf
230 /var/lib/ghostscript
516 /var/lib/dkms
10511   /var/lib/dpkg
```

---

по поводу указания количества *inode* при создании файловой системы можно прочесть, например, в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430442/178576

Comment: Уровень использования inode ещё можно посмотреть: `df -i`

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - надо почистить диск. Три с половиной миллиона файлов - это как-то очень много. Что там вообще в них хранится?

Дальше, если есть возможность управления разделами диска - надо изменить настройки файловой системы. Возможно, имеет смысл выделить отдельный раздел для тех директорий, где хранится слишком много мелких файлов.

Если такой возможности нет, или вы не умеете администрировать линукс - то надо писать в саппорт.

Comment: А как найти каталог где хранится большое количество файлов?